# ASP MVC4 membership VS2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider, simplemembership

Here's a funny one - I suspect because I am using VS 2010 with MVC4.

Created an MVC4 App using the internet template. I get AccountController.cs and the basic pages allow me to register and add users. So far so good. However, the ASP.NET configuration tool (from Project menu) seems to be using a different database.

Web.config has this:

but my MVC project also has a ASPNETDB.MDF inside app_data. ASP.NET configuration tool seems to be using ASPNETDB.MDF, but run time seems to be using the one referenced by DefaultConnection.

Also, after doing some research on here and elsewhere, other people's Web.Config seem to have lots of entries for providers etc. which I don't have. Am I missing some update / NuGet package?

All I want to do is use MVC4 with users and roles, and was planning to use the configuration tool to setup the predefined roles and some basic users.

Thanks in advance,

Ray

Comment: The web site administration tool is not compatible with the membership provider used by MVC 4 by default. See: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Comment: Yes thanks for that. That link is not an easy read but I got it. At the end of the day it looks like you have to implement your own role management / user management if you use the simple provider, which is the default with MVC4.

Comment: @RBrowning99 - You may find this useful http://www.mvccentral.net/Story/Details/tools/kahanu/securityguard-nuget-package-for-asp-net-membership

Comment: @SBirthare - hi thanks for that. I had already looked at it and but it does say it doesn't work with simplemembershipprovider. So if I don't use the simplemanagement provider, what does this tool give me that I would have just using the old provider and the WSAT tool?Thanks Ray